# How can I extend the time when system.log gets turned over?

Tags: macos, terminal, logs

Right now my system.log gets recreated every 24 hours or so with a message like:

```
Jan  4 00:30:01 Mac newsyslog[63416]: logfile turned over
```

Can I change a setting such that it will get rotated every month? Or every week?

Having a much longer time would allow for better visibility of the progression of some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system calls `newsyslog` to prune files every time a 30th minute arrives (or a little bit later if the machine is either extremely busy or sleeping).

You can see the [man page for newsyslog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/newsyslog.8.html) and [it's configuration file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/newsyslog.conf.5.html) or just dive in and edit the configuration file `/etc/newsyslog.conf`

For a pruning each month at midnight, you would change the time from @T00 to $M1D0 or for weekly on sunday at 3 AM to $W0D03

You might want to make sure you have enough space on your filesystem for a month - especially if you get some noisy software. You can also prune on size for a while if you wish, since that's easier to know when you'll want a prune based on how large a file you expect.

Answer (score 3):

You use **newsyslog** command. There is plenty of online documentation out there on how to do this, but here's a start:

https://serverfault.com/questions/264292/osx-var-log-system-log-where-do-i-define-pruning-interval

Comment: Thanks for the link to another answer - I've filled in some of the details as many people here aren't as savvy with man pages as SF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking for ways to establish a timeframe for a crash, then either of the following may help:

```
% sysctl -a | grep boottime

% last | grep crash
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your ultimate goal is to trace the history of information in the system.log files, you could, as an alternative, try `grep` from the command line, and search all system logs at once. I'm not a pro with `grep`, but looking for something like "shutdown" in all logs could be done via:

> `grep shutdown /var/log/system.log*`

This would produce a single output with any line containing the word "shutdown". The `*` at the end is a regular expression that expands the search to all files starting with `system.log`, regardless of the extension that follows (e.g., `system.log.0.bz2, system.log.0.bz3`). If you grok regular expressions, aka "regex" (I do not), then you can further augment this kind of search and make it ridiculously powerful and specific. You can check out [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) for more information about regular expressions.

Also, if you wanted to view the results outside of Terminal, you could pipe the results to a plain text file via:

> `grep shutdown system.log* | ~/Desktop/results.txt`

I realize this doesn't restructure your system logs, but it does get you the end result you're looking for.